# 2007 Mercury Mariner - Car is shaking and whining.

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, rough-idle, mercury

Today my car starting shaking and whining very badly, but only when I'm stopped and the car is in drive. If I put it in park or neutral the vibration stops. The shaking stops as soon as I start to accelerate but the whine will continue until I get over 30mph. The whine sounds like what a toy, remote controlled car sounds like.

No alerts/warnings lights have come on, it's not over heating and I can't smell anything burning under the hood. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Can you get a video with sound? Any time something is a little bit wrong with a vehicle's powertrain, there will be some shaking. :)